# Tridion 2011 Core Service - error updating component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to update a component using Tridion Core Services. This is how my method looks like:

```
public ComponentData Update(ComponentData component)
        {            
            return _session.Client.Update(component, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
        }
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

It is not possible to check-out a shared item

I tried checking in the component before updating but got the same error again. Can you give me any tips on what I am doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update a shared item in a child Publication. That is not allowed.

If your intention was to only modify the item in the current Publication and all child Publications in it is, you should call Localize first.

If you instead intended to update the Component everywhere, you should use the version of the Component URI from the parent Publication where the item was created.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was opening the item in 06 level instead of 04 level where the components are able to be edited. Do you by any chance know how we can open an editable version of a component? I changed the level but now I am getting error that IsEditable is false. This is how I read...  public ComponentData Read(string webDav)
        {
            var result = _session.Client.Read(webDav, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
            return result;
        }

Comment: You have to call CheckOut first. I'd specify "false" for permanentLock .

Comment: Yes I had to call CheckOut() (reed was not needed), Update the return object, Update() and CheckIn(). It also worked with Save() used instead of Update(). Thanks for your help!